# exception in servletsum program

Tags: servlets

```
    import javax.servlet.GenericServlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;`enter code here`
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.Exception;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
public class SumServlet extends GenericServlet
{
    public void service(ServletRequest request,ServletResponse response)throws ServletException,IOException
    {

            String str1=request.getParameter("fname");
            String str2=request.getParameter(" sname");
            int num1=Integer.parseInt(str1);
            int num2=Integer.parseInt(str2);
            int  sum=num1+num2;
            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
            out.println("Given fnumber  is   "+str1);
            out.println(" --------------");
            out.println("Given second number is"+str2);
            out.println(" --------------");
            out.println("Sum of numbers is "+sum);
    }
 }



 /*There is an exception arises with this program as http status 500:null.
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
        java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
        java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
        SumServlet.service(SumServlet.java:17)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52).
```

the above message is obtained as exception when this program is run on tomcat server by passig values using query string..at what line of above casues this exception and give solution to overcome this exception.
.*/

Answer (score 0):

Deadly noob code

```
public void service(ServletRequest request,ServletResponse response)throws ServletException,IOException
    {
            String str1=request.getParameter("fname");
            String str2=request.getParameter("sname");// " sname" is not "sname"
            boolean err=true;
            try{//try to convert String to int
            int num1=Integer.parseInt(str1);
            int num2=Integer.parseInt(str2);err=false;
            }catch(Exception ex){}
            if(err){out.println("Invalid number format provided");}
            else{int  sum=num1+num2;
            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
            out.println("Given fnumber  is   "+str1);
            out.println(" --------------");
            out.println("Given second number is"+str2);
            out.println(" --------------");
            out.println("Sum of numbers is "+sum);
            }
    }
```